par rapport, expression déroutante ?
In Manon des sources, a young schoolteacher newly come to the rural Provençal town has this exchange with the townsfolk (p. 80; might need to borrow the book to see):

— (Instituteur) Et où se trouve-t-elle, votre source, par rapport à ce bassin ?
— (Ugolin) Comment ça, par rapport ?
— (Instituteur) Est-elle plus haut ou plus bas ?
— (Ugolin) C'est difficile à dire ...
— (Ange) À mon idée, le vallon des Romarins c'est un peu plus haut.

I have my theories about why this expression might be perplexing, but it would be good to know the actual reason(s).

Perhaps it normally indicates an abstract relationship, not a concrete one. "Relative to" or something like that.
Perhaps it's of an academic register, not used by paysans.
Perhaps it's Parisian or otherwise foreign to those living near Aubagne.
Perhaps it only gained currency shortly before the story is set (the instituteur is ~10 years younger than Ugolin).
Perhaps it's used incorrectly here.

In the same line of thinking, is there an expression the instituteur could have used that wouldn't have prompted the need for clarification?

In addition to @Frank's answer, note that the schoolmaster could also be asking about the direction of the spring relative to the point of reference, rather than the relative height.

The question itself is not ambiguous, that par rapport is perfectly appropriate. But Ugolin doesn't really want to reveal where the source is, and so is feigning confusion, or surprise. The topic makes him uncomfortable, he is trying to stall and avoid answering.
In general, "par rapport" could conceivably elicit a request for more precision, but I don't think it's the dominant factor here. L'instituteur is trying to elicit precise information, he is not asking where the source is in general, but precisely, in relationship to the bassin. That is certainly too precise for Ugolin, who recoils.

Interesting thought. To your point, Ugolin goes on to answer vaguely and a concitoyen has to answer for him, which I've added to the question. That would be in line with numerous instances in both JdF and Mds where Ugolin and César avoid showing that they know too much about the spring — although by now it's been common knowledge for years that they've discovered and are using it. Still, it seems (as you say in your last sentence) that unless there was something potentially unclear in the question, Ugolin's would be an odd reply.

I think it's clear and he is just stalling :-)

The OP's remarks:

Perhaps it normally indicates an abstract relationship, not a concrete one. "Relative to" or something like that.
Response: No, it can refer to any relationship, physical or abstract.
Perhaps it's of an academic register, not used by paysans.
Response: It is not an academic register. It is used all the time by native speakers of French.
Perhaps it's Parisian or otherwise foreign to those living near Aubagne.
Response: Not likely at all.
Perhaps it only gained currency shortly before the story is set (the instituteur is ~10 years younger than Ugolin).
Response: The use has been around for ages.
Perhaps it's used incorrectly here.
Response: No, it's used correctly to compare the position of the spring to the pond. The spring relative to the pond. That's the translation for physical objects.

It's often used for the position of one thing to another. Things physical and abstract and relationships between people. It is most definitely not academic. Spend one day in France with your peers and you are likely to hear it.  Below are some examples taken from physical uses. It is used correctly in the story. It's so very French and used everywhere and all the time.
In the dictionary:

Par rapport à, loc. prép. [D'un point de vue spatial]

Savons-nous cette fois ce que c'est qu'un point défini ainsi par sa position relative par rapport à nous (H. Poincaré, Valeur sc.,1905, p. 80).Par comparaison avec, en proportion de. Yvonne: De toute façon, cette petite est beaucoup trop jeune. (...) Georges: Elle a trois ans de plus que Michel. Hier tu la trouvais trop vieille... Yvonne: Elle est trop jeune... par rapport à moi (Cocteau, Parents,1938, iii, 2, p. 280).Pour ce qui regarde, relativement à.
cntrl.fr
2)
Où est situé le bâtiment par rapport à la rue et aux limites séparatives ?
plan masse
3)
Pour faire le bon choix des assises pour une salle de conférence, il faut vérifier l’espace à aménager, la hauteur de la chaise par rapport à la table, son ergonomie, son esthétisme et sa robustesse.
quadra-mobilier.fr
4)
Physical space
Dire que deux figures sont symétriques par rapport à une droite signifie que,
en effectuant un pliage le long de la droite, les figures se superposent.
cours
That said, as I recall the movie, as I have not read this Pagnol book, Ugolin is a simpleton, kind of the "village idiot". Here's a great overview from Le Figaro:

WEB-SERIE 10/25 - Ce rôle d'idiot du village, qui manigance une ruse
meurtrière avec son oncle, «le Papet», fera connaître la consécration
en 1986 à Daniel Auteuil qui reçoit le César du meilleur acteur pour
sa prestation dans Jean de Florette et Manon des sources.
Le moins que l'on puisse dire, c'est que le dernier des Soubeyran ne
fait pas honneur à la lignée. Physiquement d'abord, sans être vraiment
laid, il n'est pas très ragoûtant avec ses yeux jaunes agités de tics,
qui «parpelègent» comme on dit au pays, et son air fuyant de bête aux
aguets. Pour le reste, il n'est pas très capable: faible de tête et de
cœur, il prospère à l'ombre de son oncle qui le bouscule et lui
fournit ce qui lui manque de jugement et d'idées -à dire vrai, il est
un peu couillon.
Ugolin

So, the point re Ugolin is not that he's a peasant, but that he is simple. That's why he is perplexed. Today, we'd say developmentally challenged...
[Please do not edit those to paragraph marks. Thanks.]

Interesting. Nevertheless, I'm not fully convinced that Ugolin's dimwittedness alone accounts for his not understanding it. Though he lacks judgement, he does and says things (in both book and movie) that would make it hard to believe he doesn't understand such an apparently basic expression. I have a new theory: he understands the other meaning of "rapport" as well and is surprised that the spring and the basin might have any relation to each other, that one might feed the other or come from the same source. This ties in with people's later befuddlement face à the geological expert.

@LukeSawczak Well, you can believe Le Figaro or not. He was in on the plot, but that doesn't make him bright, does it? But he does go on to answer the question in fact by saying it's hard to say, once it's clarified for him. So, we really have no way of knowing.
